# When making network requests, when should I use Threads vs Processes?

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing

I'm working on a Ruby script that will be making hundreds of network requests (via `open-uri`) to various APIs and I'd like to do this in parallel since each request is slow, and blocking.

I have been looking at using `Thread` or `Process` to achieve this but I'm not sure which method to use.

With regard to network request, when should i use a `Thread` over `Process`, or does it not matter?

Comment: If you plan on making hundreds of them, `Process` seems like a non-starter.

Answer (score 2):

Before going into detail, there is already a library solving your problem. **[Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus)** is optimized to run a large number of HTTP requests in parallel and is based on the libcurl library.

> Like a modern code version of the mythical beast with 100 serpent
>   heads, **Typhoeus** runs HTTP requests in parallel while cleanly
>   encapsulating handling logic.

**Threads** will be run in the same process as your application. Since Ruby 1.9 native threads are used as the underlying implementation. Resources can be easily shared across threads, as they all can access the mutual state of the application. The problem, however, is that you cannot utilize the multiple cores of your CPU with most Ruby implementations.

Ruby uses the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). GIL is a locking mechanism to ensure that the mutual state is not corrupted due to parallel modifications from different threads. Other Ruby implementations like JRuby, Rubinius or MacRuby offer an approach without GIL.

**Processes** run separately from each other. Processes do not share resources, which means every process has its own state. This can be a problem, if you want to share data across your requests. A process also allocates its own stack of memory. You could still share data by using a messaging bus like RabitMQ.

I cannot recommend to use either only threads or only processes. If you want to implement that yourself, you should use both. Fork for every *n*  requests a new processes which then again spawns a number of threads to issue the HTTP requests. Why?

If you fork for every HTTP request another process, this will result in too many processes. Although your operating system might be able to handle this, the overhead is still tremendous. Some HTTP requests might finish very fast, so why bother with an extra process, just run them in another thread.